# How to enable "azurerm_security_center_subscription_pricing" across multiple resource in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to manage security center through TF resource, however have been hitting an error.

This is how the code looks like:

```
resource "azurerm_security_center_subscription_pricing" "example" {
  count         = var.enabled && var.subscription_pricing_enabled ? 1 : 0
  tier          = var.tier
  resource_type = "VirtualMachines, AppServices, ContainerRegistry, KeyVaults, KubernetesService, SqlServers, SqlServerVirtualMachines, StorageAccounts, Arm, Dns"
```

=========================================================================================================

```
Error: [0m[0m[1mexpected resource_type to be one of [AppServices ContainerRegistry KeyVaults KubernetesService SqlServers SqlServerVirtualMachines StorageAccounts VirtualMachines], got VirtualMachines, AppServices, ContainerRegistry, KeyVaults, KubernetesService, SqlServers, SqlServerVirtualMachines, StorageAccounts, Arm, Dns[0m
2021-04-03T07:20:07.7838074Z 
2021-04-03T07:20:07.7838690Z [0m  on primary_azure_defender.tf line 54, in resource "azurerm_security_center_subscription_pricing" "example":
2021-04-03T07:20:07.7839390Z   54: resource "azurerm_security_center_subscription_pricing" "example" [4m{[0
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Documentation doesn't provide much details on this usage: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/security_center_subscription_pricing

Answer (score 1):

In main.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_security_center_subscription_pricing" "tier" {
  tier          = "Standard"
  for_each      = toset(var.security_center_resource_types)
  resource_type = each.value
}
```

In Variables.tf:

```
variable security_center_resource_types {
  description = "List of security center resource types to configure"
  type        = list(string)
  default = [
"VirtualMachines",
"AppServices",
"KeyVaults",
"SqlServers",
"SqlServerVirtualMachines",
"StorageAccounts",
"Arm",
"Dns",
"Containers",
"OpenSourceRelationalDatabases"
```

]
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide **only one** value for `resource_type`, e.g.:

```
resource "azurerm_security_center_subscription_pricing" "example" {
  count         = var.enabled && var.subscription_pricing_enabled ? 1 : 0
  tier          = var.tier
  resource_type = "VirtualMachines"
```

The possible value are listed in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/security_center_subscription_pricing#resource_type) and in your error message.

Comment: Agree. But you can Select Azure defender Plan for selective resources in the portal, e.g. servers, storage accounts, Azure SQL Databases, Kubernetes etc. I am unable to do it through terraform.

Comment: @hpmi Maybe you have to create multiple `azurerm_security_center_subscription_pricing` resources. Or maybe what you want is simply not supported by TF?